# using javascript to call a fileset function array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using the following JavaScript function array to control the use of two sets of radio buttons on my page. The array works perfectly like this whilst in the confines of the head element but I would like to learn how to call it from a **.js** file .
This is the array:-

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(function() {
        $(".fileset :radio").on("change", function() {
            var div = $(this).parent();
            var id = div.attr("id").split("-")[1];
            var values = [];    
            div.find(":checked").each(function() {
                values.push(this.value);
            });
            $("#file-" + id).val(values.join(","));
        });
    });
</script>
```

The html coding is as follows, also working perfectly:

```
<div class="c1"><strong>Marital Status</strong>
<input type="text" name="gstats" value="" id="file-1" size="5"     class="filestosend" />
                            </div>
                                <div id="fileset-1" class="fileset"><strong>Never Married</strong>
                                <input type="radio" value="NVM" name="GSTATS" onclick="change" tabindex="46" /> <strong>Divorced</strong>
                                <input type="radio" value="DIV" name="GSTATS" onclick="change" tabindex="47" /> <strong>Widowed</strong>
                                <input type="radio" value="WID" name="GSTATS" onclick="change" tabindex="48" /> <strong>Nullity</strong>
                                <input type="radio" value="NUL" name="GSTATS" onclick="change" tabindex="49" />
                            </div>
```

I have created a test.js file using the data in the fileset function array and am having difficulty calling it it the html.  I have tried placing the script tage before and after the div tags without success.  Is there a possible solution.

Comment: Maybe you have a problem in the order you load your scripts. Please show us the whole HTML page

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is create a .js file, don't use the tag `<script>` in the js file. Place it somewhere, for example: You have a map called 'website', with 'website' you have your html file, a map called 'scripts' and within 'scripts' 'myscript.js'.

In your html file you place this: `<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/myscript.js></script>"`

Comment: Thank you, however I have already done that.  I have created the .js file and have placed the correct call in the head of my html file:      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/radiobutton.js></script>"   However I have tried several methods to call it from the radio button array in my html code.

Comment: @IvanConway you don't need to call anything if your script loading is perfect. It'll bind an eventhandler to the radio button change event once the document is ready.

Answer (score 0):

I realised that the answer was really simple.
Firstly I checked the coding of the radio button list and noted that the div  class was named "fileset":

```
<div id="fileset-1" class="fileset">
<input type="radio" value="NVM" name="GSTATS" onclick="change" tabindex="46" /> <strong>Never Married</strong>
<input type="radio" value="DIV" name="GSTATS" onclick="change" tabindex="47" />  <strong>Divorced</strong>
<input type="radio" value="WID" name="GSTATS" onclick="change" tabindex="48" /> <strong>Widowed</strong>
<input type="radio" value="NUL" name="GSTATS" onclick="change" tabindex="49" /> <strong>Nullity</strong>
```

Then it was just a simple matter of renaming my .js file to fileset.js and calling on it accordingly.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/fileset.js'></script>
```

Thanks once again for advice given.